# Exp-resso store, iDeal payments: AP1200: IssuerID unknown

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, checkout

First things first:
I'm running on EE 2.5.3, Expresso Store 1.6.1. All certificates are in place.

On the final step of the checkout process, after choosing "iDeal" and an issuer, i get an  error:

> IssuerID unknown (AP1200: Field generating error: IssuerID unknown)

I think this means the issuerID is incorrect.

The code i'm using:

```
<select name="payment[issuer]"> 
<option selected value="">Selecteer uw bank...</option> 
<option value="0031">ABN AMRO</option> 
<option value="0091">Friesland Bank</option> 
<option value="0721">ING</option> 
<option value="0021">Rabobank</option> 
<option value="0751">SNS Bank</option> 
<option value="0761">ASN Bank</option> 
<option value="0771">SNS Regio Bank</option> 
<option value="0511">Triodos Bank</option> 
<option value="0161">Van Lanschot</option> 
</select>
```

How can i make sure Expresso Store supplies my bank with the correct issuerID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where are you getting that list of issuers from?

You should be using this, it will automatically load the list of issuers and cache it:

```
<select name="payment[issuer]">
    {ideal_issuer_options}
</select>
```

Mostly likely, I'm guessing you have the gateway in test mode, and it will be expecting you to use the test issuer (which the iDeal gateway will output when you use the snippet above), rather than one of the live issuers.

Comment: This is the list you (Adrian) sent me when ideal was not officially supported. The {ideal_issuer_options} code works.  Thanks!

Comment: Aha. It's supported now, glad that worked!